# Fastest way to find indices of a 3-D numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 3-D numpy array from which I need to find the indices of the locations in the array which have values greater than 0.

```
voxel_space = np.random.rand(100, 240, 180)
```

I currently use the following numpy method to solve my problem.

```
vol_vectors = np.argwhere(voxel_space > 0)
```

While this works, it is quite slow for my application. I was wondering if there was a faster way to do the same.

Comment: Then shouldn't your code be `np.argwhere(voxel_space>0)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: How do you use `vol_vectors`? Why do you need list of indexes? Usually you should do just `vol_vectors = voxel_space > 0` and than use the mask `vol_vectors` to filter whatever  you need to.